# Keyboard Shortcut for Show Windows Stacked? (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

Does anyone know of a keyboard shortcut, to avoid right-clicking on the taskbar, that would show windows stacked?

Answer (score 3):

1. <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>   (puts focus on taskbar)
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>   (puts focus on "Show hidden icons" arrow)
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>   (contextual menu)
4. Select "Show windows stacked" and press Enter.

It's a long way, not a shortcut. But it avoids mouse pointing and right clicking.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that sadly, Windows doesn't allow this by default.

I found [this forum post](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/144512-show-windows-stacked-side-side-create-shortcuts.html) which provides a way to add a shortcut to stacking windows with a VBS file

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this, but

1. <kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> gives the taskbar focus on the first item.
2. Use the right arrow key to get to the stacked application
3. Press up arrow to go into the stack.
4. Use the arrow keys the navigate, then enter