# Windows tool to resize and place three windows

Tags: windows, desktop

By pressing <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> I can place 2 windows alongside each other, taking 50% of the available space. Is there a utility which can help me to place 3 windows alongside each other? Or maybe even fit 4 windows alongside each other?

Answer (score 1):

Using two monitors would work for four windows using your way. JK. :)

Just right click the blank part on the taskbar (or the clock) and select "Show windows side by side".

[Found it here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/place-two-windows-side-by-side-in-windows-8.html)

Also there's a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/287518/keyboard-shortcut-for-show-windows-stacked-win-7) here on SU about shortcuts (hotkeys) and `bruno077` suggested a website with solution to that: [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/144512-show-windows-stacked-side-side-create-shortcuts.html).

Comment: thanks for you helpful answer. The stacking option is great but lacking some control. I work with 2 monitors. If i could "stack" on one monitor only that would be a good start. The best solution for me would be to have more than just the "left half" and "right half" hotkeys.

Comment: @Niksac you can minimize the windows except the ones you want to stack, then move them to the monitors that you want to stack and select stack. That way those windows will be stacked on that screen only