# Windows 10 keyboard shortcut to vertically move a window to another monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm aware that you can move windows between monitors using the `Windows logo key` + `Ctrl` + `Left/Right arrow` combo.

But this only works horizontally, when the monitors are side by side. I would like to do this, but with monitors stacked vertically.

[image]

Unfortunately, the `Windows logo key` + `Ctrl` + `Up/Down arrow` combo maximizes/minimizes the window, and the left/right arrows combination doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Try Win + Shift + right/left-arrow.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. Would you like to post an Answer?

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcut
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>
or
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>
will move the active window to the left or right monitor,
or actually to the next or previous monitor.

This will also work for the horizontal arrangement of monitors.

Answer (score 1):

### A)

**You can use the `Windows Stacked` in the `Taskbar` by set of shortcuts**
[image]

*Emilio* has guided in [his answer](https://superuser.com/questions/287518/keyboard-shortcut-for-show-windows-stacked-win-7/1179482#1179482) :

> 1. <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>   (puts focus on taskbar)
> 2. <kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>   (puts focus on "Show hidden icons" arrow)
> 3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>   (contextual menu)
> 4. Select "Show windows stacked" and press Enter.
>
> It's a long way, not a shortcut. But it avoids mouse pointing and
>   right clicking.

---

### B)

**You can use bellow shortcuts to make a foursome set of windows:**

1. Focus on the **first window** then **use** » <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> then <kbd>Up</kbd> OR other <kbd>Arrow keys...</kbd> you want
2. Select **next window** by <kbd>Arrow keys...</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (*if the window show you the window selection panel automatically*) OR <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> OR <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Go to the step 1

Result:
[image]